# Setting Default Timezone on Symfony2 with Bluehost Shared Hosting

Tags: php, symfony, shared-hosting, bluehost

I installed Symfony2 on my shared hosting server with Bluehost. But when I run the command "php -cli app/console generate:bundle", I get the following message:

> Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.

When I type php -cli | php.ini, I get the /usr/php/54/etc folder which I am not allowed to write on with shared hosting.
So what I did is add this code to the AppKernel.php

> ```
> public function __construct($environment, $debug)
> {
>     date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
>     parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
> }
> ```

Then I got this error:

> Bundle namespace:  Notice: Use of undefined constant STDIN - assumed 'STDIN'

So I also had to add this line to the AppKernel.php:

> define('STDIN',fopen("php://stdin","r"));

I believe changing the AppKernel.php is a bad practice (is it?). Are there any other means to change the php.ini that my Symfony project uses on shared hosting with Bluehost? I tried to use the one in the public_html folder by selecting the PHP Single php.ini from my control panel, but it doesn't seem to work for php -cli.

Many thanks for your answers.